# Is there on Instagram an official way to get photos according to hashtag but from ALL users and not only from the one related to the client id?

Tags: php, tags, instagram, social-networking, hashtag

I know it's super easy to retrieve photos from Instagram according to a specific hashtag from your own profile (with the **client id** used in the connection to the library), but I could not find anything official to retrieve photos with an hashtag, independently by the users.

So, for instance, if my hashtag was **test**, an API grabbing a PHP object containing photos as in this [link](https://instagram.com/explore/tags/test/) as in the following code

```
$o_instagram = new Instagram($s_client_id);
$o_media = $o_instagram->searchTags($s_hashtag);
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually that query grabs really all photos users, I just realized that the difference between that query and the link `https://instagram.com/explore/tags/test/` is that the second one grabs the most popular photos with that hashtag

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following endpoint

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent

I'm not sure how it looks in their php library but in ruby is is something along the lines of `Instagram_client.tag_recent_media(:tag)`

It's paginated in order of most recent first